# DefaultModelBinding to never have a null element in collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with a `List<Section> Sections` in it, my clients can send null values in this collection, I want to initialize them with default constructor of Section.

How can it be done for all Collections in ViewModels at once?

I'm trying to achieve this with extending `DefaultBinder` - but the problem is that `CreateModel` is not called for a null

Comment: What do you mean they can send null values? Do you mean some properties of `Section` are `null`?

Comment: so you don't want a default instance nor do you want nulls. how does that work?

Comment: Json is sent from clients, and I can have an array with null in this json, something like Sections: [null]

Comment: @Steve - I do want a default instance.

Comment: @Anarion then you either initialize them with default constructor of Section or you can make a variable to store an empty instance of section and add it to the list. But at the end of the day you are either checking == null or == EmptySection

Comment: Where do I initialize them? I was debugging CreateModel of my class that extends DefaultModelBinder, and I never hit a model of collection elements.

Comment: Is it feasible to just make `Section` a struct instead of a class?  That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's a complex class, I don't think switching to struct is a good option

Comment: Added last paragraph trying to explain better what I'm doing.

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve? If the client sends `Sections: [null]` which will initialize your collection property with one `null` item, do you want to remove that item (so its an empty collection), or do you want to replace the `null` instance with a default instance?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want a default instance instead of null.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1207991/215552